# Como fazer um efeito adicionando um novo item a uma lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho uma lista que atualiza de tempos em tempos e gostaria de adicionar um efeito igual ao deste site: [Site](http://www.oppettider.nu/)

É a lista que está no meio do site.

Onde, quando um item novo entra na lista, o restante dos itens descem fazendo um efeito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estou supondo que você está interessado apenas na parte visual da coisa, e que já tenha resolvido a parte de trazer os dados do servidor.

Criei um exemplo bem básico, usando jQuery. Não é exatamente igual ao do site, mas acho que fica com uma didática melhor.

### Código HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="new-item" />
<input type="button" value="Adicionar" id="add-item" />

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

### Código Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add-item').on('click', function() {
        var itemText = $('#new-item').val();

        var newEl = $('<li>' + itemText + '</li>');
        newEl.hide();

        $('ul').prepend(newEl);

        newEl.slideDown();

    });
});
```

O `prepend` adiciona um elemento no ínicio. Ele fica escondido por padrão (`hide`), e depois é mostrado com o efeito `slideDown`.

Para testar, é só escrever alguma coisa no textbox e clicar em "Adicionar". Criei um jsFiddle para facilitar: http://jsfiddle.net/V4aDn/

Se você quer deixar *exatamente* igual ao do site, será necessário estilizar, e também manipular os detalhes da velocidade do efeito.

Answer (score 5):

O que o site está fazendo é bem simples:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        var i=0;
        if($("ul.senasteList li:first").hasClass("odd")) i = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "senaste.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { lastid: $("ul.senasteList li:first").attr("id") , i: i},
            success: function (data) 
            {
                if(data.length > 0)
                {
                    $("ul.senasteList").html(data).find("li:first").hide().show("blind", {percent: 100}, 350);
                    $("ul.senasteList li:last").fadeOut(100, function() { $("ul.senasteList li:last").remove(); });
                }
            }
        });

    }, 1000);
```

Basicamente o truque está aqui (expandi o código um pouco pra simplificar o entendimento):

```
$("ul.senasteList").html(data);
$("ul.senasteList li:first").hide();
$("ul.senasteList li:first").show("blind", {percent: 100}, 350);
$("ul.senasteList li:last").fadeOut(100, function() {
    $("ul.senasteList li:last").remove();
});
```

Ele obtém e substitui o código HTML completo da lista, mas antes que o navegador renderize esse HTML ele usa jQuery para esconder o primeiro elemento, e define para mostra-lo com interpolação.

Ao mesmo tempo aplica uma interpolação de desaparecimento no último elemento, que ao concluir remove-o.

O `senaste.php` encarrega-se de gerar a nova lista em PHP. Se o `lastid` provido pelo AJAX for igual ao `lastid` atual, o `senaste.php` não retorna dados, então a lista não é atualizada.

Comment: +1 Estava escrevendo uma resposta, mas você foi mais rápido. Deixo aqui meu exemplo pra referência: http://jsfiddle.net/aUDmr/

Comment: Também é um jeito bem interessante de resolver a questão.